# Get Module name with function + offset

Tags: multithreading, function, dll, process, module

I am trying to figure out how to get the function of a module + offset of a thread. Similiar to how Process Explorer does in it's thread display. Example....

ntdll!TplsTimerSet+0x07c0

I can pull the start address with no problem, and I can also resolved the start address to the module.  I can get the start address to show "ntdll.dll" plus the offset (startaddress - baseaddress), but not the function. So mine looks like this..

ntdll+3BC0C

I would like to locate which function of the ntdll dll the offset resides in. In this case the function is Tplstimerset. I know that I will have to calculate the diffence of the offset and the address of the function, but that should be easy. This code can be in C++ of Delphi/Pascal. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In Process Explorer -> Options -> Configure Symbols, you can see symbols files are used in order to resolve functions.

These symbols are from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/symbols-and-symbol-files) and both windbg and Visual Studio are using them when debugging.

[image]

If you started windbg and have loaded one executable file, type "x ntdll!*" to show all named functions of ntdll, the asterisk means it matches all.

[image]

I assume you need to get the addresses of named functions programmatically, you may need the [.pdb file specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb).